# Consistently oscillating micron sized particles in a liquid

Tags: experimental-physics, specific-reference, laser

I have an idea that would involve the measurement of an oscillating substance whilst the substance is immersed in a liquid.  However, the method that I would use to measure the frequency of these oscillations is a novel one.  Therefore, I need a benchmark.

Thus, can anyone direct me to a paper that gives the details - frequency, amplitude, characteristic size of the particles, etc. - of some kind of micron sized particle that will undergo oscillations when being excited by some kind of light source?

I've spoken to others in my department, and they have mentioned gold particles as such a benchmark.  However, I have been unable to find a good paper detailing the types of vibrations I would need (i.e. the creation of longitudinal waves) under laser irradiation.  Details on gold would, therefore, do the job nicely, but any such sized micron sized particle details would be great.

Spherical particles would be preferable given the geometry of my setup.

Comment: With micro-sized particles suspended in a liquid you will have to contend with Brownian motion as a significant background. Indeed I would look for references on measuring such motions to use as a starting point.

Comment: Why don't you give more detail about what you are trying to measure and how? It's pretty unlikely that it's actually novel, but there's not enough info here to give a useful recommendation.

Comment: @zephyr the method that I am employing IS novel, that's kind of the point of trying to develop it as a part of getting my PhD.  So, no, I won't share anymore details to the method itself.  What I need is a benchmark to test the method.  Therefore, what I am asking for is anything that can be used as such a benchmark.  I need a micron sized, spherical something that oscillates with a well characterized amplitude and frequency in response to a laser or light whilst immersed in a liquid.  Anything that anyone has heard of that can do this will do the trick.  And reference would be wonderful!

Comment: @pballjew the more you progress in science, the more you will realize hardly anything is truly novel - particularly so in a squishy field like it sounds you are working in. Trying to conceal what you are doing is pointless and counterproductive. If you tell us the details we have a much better chance of being able to give you useful advice. Or at least make your requirements more clear - what kind of oscillations? What amplitude and frequency range is useful? I can think of dozens of ways to make particles move, but I have no idea what you are looking for.

Comment: There is a time and place for secrecy in order to protect your priority, and there are times and places where it is just plain silly. If neither you nor your adviser know anything about these measurements then neither of you is in a position to know if your work is novel or not. You need to talk to someone with some experience in the field.

Comment: Guys, really.  Let me clarify my request:  I do not need help with the method I will be employing to detect vibration.  I'm not keeping it secret out of some sort of fear as much as its details are not relevant to my question.  I'm an experimentalist.  Therefore, my experiment is the goal.  Of course, if I get stuck on some aspect of the experiment I will give all the detail necessary when asking for help from the forum.  What I do need is a benchmark, something that my apparatus can see that has defined characteristics in liquid that I can use to see if my detection method is nonsense or not.

Comment: @pballjew - the point is, when you don't give any detail on your measurement, how are we supposed to know what kind of benchmark would be useful? Certainly we could go back and forth with people suggesting things, then you explaining why that particular suggestion isn't suitable, etc. etc. but that is just a waste of everyone's time. Plus, we're all curious by nature ;)

Comment: Anyway, more on topic: I would suggest that you find the most common existing technique in the literature used for the application that you envision, and find a way to perform that in tandem with your novel technique. Validating against an established measurement method will usually be more convincing than testing on a model system which may or may not be behaving as you expect it to.

Answer (score -1):

Micron sized things, I am thinking of the biological experiments. Maybe you should try them. They got fluids, and all kinds of cells or single-cell plants or whatever. Cells also respond to electricity, maybe in some form of oscillation.

Comment: Sorry for the -1, but this is a comment, not an answer.